# Parallax scrolling header in RecyclerView with multiple view types

Tags: android

The title pretty much explains my need. I have `RecyclerView` and adapter with N amount of view types. I have tried 3 different third party libraries (e.g. https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview) which should support parallax header view. None of them seem to work or need custom adapter which doesn't apply to my use case. Maybe they are internally playing with view types.

Is there some library which would support multiple view types in adapter and parallax scrolling header?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question - I'm also interested in doing something similar to what you have asked.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be so many implementations and some might work, but only if the whole adapter is rewritten to match its needs.

Comment: Do you want the header background to scroll with a parallax effect? If so, I would look into item decorations. Then you can just draw the background as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ItemDecoration to add a parallax background to specific items. This is just some simple code and can be improved in lots of ways.

```
public class ParallaxHeaderDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private Bitmap mImage;

    public ParallaxHeaderDecoration(final Context context, @DrawableRes int resId) {
        mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 20) {
                int offset = view.getTop() / 3;
                c.drawBitmap(mImage, new Rect(0, offset, mImage.getWidth(), view.getHeight() + offset),
                        new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom()), null);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

With the item decoration characteristics you can just paint bg to specific views or positions.

[image: RecyclerView with parallax background]

And you can see a more complex sample at https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations

Comment: My header in RecyclerView is a lot bigger than other items are and I would like it to parallax scroll slower up and not get invisible at all.

Comment: So make it bigger. This sample is just to show one way of doing it, not a finished solution :) @Niko what do you mean by not get invisible at all? Like sticky headers? For something like that you will have to make your own layout manager